# Factory pattern for getting xml data

Tags: java, object-oriented, design-patterns

i am  trying to implement factory pattern for getting XML Document from server

(using javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder)

I have the classes below for now, could you give your opinion ? Does the structure  make sense for this pattern?

**DocumentGeneratorFactory** (abstract factory)

```
public interface DocumentGeneratorFactory {

    public Document createDocument(String scheme, String authority,
            String path, HashMap<String, String> parameters)
            throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException;

    public Document createDocument(String scheme, String authority,String path)
            throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException;
}
```

**ProductDocumentGeneratorFactory** (Concreate factory)

```
public class ProductDocumentGeneratorFactory implements
        DocumentGeneratorFactory {

    public Document createDocument(String scheme, String authority,
            String path, HashMap<String, String> parameters)
            throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {

        Uri.Builder uri = new Uri.Builder();
        uri.scheme(scheme);
        uri.authority(authority);
        uri.path(path);

        Set<Map.Entry<String, String>> set = parameters.entrySet();

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> params : set) {
            uri.appendQueryParameter(params.getKey(), params.getValue());
        }

        URL url = new URL(uri.toString());

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        return doc;
    }

    public Document createDocument(String scheme, String authority, String path)
            throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {

        Uri.Builder uri = new Uri.Builder();
        uri.scheme(scheme);
        uri.authority(authority);
        uri.path(path);

        URL url = new URL(uri.toString());

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        return doc;

    }

}
```

**Request** (Abstract Product)

```
public abstract class Request {
    Document doc;
    HashMap<String, String> queryStrings;

    abstract void prepareRequest() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException;  

}
```

**ProductRequest** (Product)

```
public class ProductRequest extends Request{
    ProductDocumentGeneratorFactory DocumentGeneratorFactory;   
    HashMap<String, String> queryStrings;

    public ProductRequest(ProductDocumentGeneratorFactory DocumentGeneratorFactory,HashMap<String, String> queryStrings){
        this.DocumentGeneratorFactory = DocumentGeneratorFactory;
        this.queryStrings = queryStrings;
    }

    @Override
    void prepareRequest() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        doc = this.DocumentGeneratorFactory.createDocument("http", "ip-address", "default.aspx",this.queryStrings);     
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Makes sense, but you should DRY up your concrete factory at least. Forgive me my rusty Java, but something like this:

```
public class ProductDocumentGeneratorFactory implements
        DocumentGeneratorFactory {

    public Document createDocument(String scheme, String authority, String path)
            throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {

        Uri.Builder uri = createUri(scheme, authority, path);
        Document doc = createDocument(uri);
        return doc;
    }

    public Document createDocument(String scheme, String authority,
            String path, HashMap<String, String> parameters)
            throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {

        Uri.Builder uri = createUri(scheme, authority, path);
        appendParameters(uri, parameters);
        Document doc = createDocument(Uri.Builder uri);
        return doc;
    }

    private Uri createUri(string scheme, string authority, string path)
    {
        Uri.Builder uri = new Uri.Builder();
        uri.scheme(scheme);
        uri.authority(authority);
        uri.path(path);
        return uri;
    }

    private Document createDocument(Uri.Builder uri)
    {
        URL url = new URL(uri.toString());

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        return doc
    }

    private void appendParameters(Uri.Builder uri, HashMap<string,string> parameters)
    {
        Set<Map.Entry<String, String>> set = parameters.entrySet();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> params : set) {
            uri.appendQueryParameter(params.getKey(), params.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you can expand on that by employing the [template pattern](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern&ei=S_W5UOzEC6zZ4QTStYGwBg&usg=AFQjCNHmRc7_Y0pUONKtb-4ToYLl5Xo_Ug&sig2=-6mD6B9d3DHrNxsAF-iscw) for the extra parameter settings.

I would also look into extracting the parameters to a "[parameter object](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ParameterObject)" instead of several parameters.